# Concourse: Use a semver resource to control which artifact to use from s3

Tags: semantic-versioning, concourse

My pipeline contains a task with the following pre-requisites

```
 - get: version  
   trigger: true
   params: { bump: patch }
   passed: ["trigger_job [CI]"]    
 - get: sdk-package
   passed: ["package_generation_job"]
   params:
     version: {path: "artifact_[I want to put the version here]"}
```

`version` is a semver stored in git; `sdk-package` is a build artifact stored in s3 where each run of the pipeline puts a new artifact using the version number as part of the name.

What I would like to do is used the `version` input to determine which version of the artifact is pulled from S3.  Based on [this](https://github.com/concourse/semver-resource/issues/48) I suspect that Concourse doesn't allow this, but I couldn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: It looks like this is already recorded as an enhancement here - https://github.com/concourse/s3-resource/issues/90

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, you will have to download the artifact you want in a task script. You can pass the version into that task.